# Prestashop - PHP - update combination quantity raises error

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to create a PHP script that updates a quantity for combinations in **PrestaShop 1.6.1.11**

I thought I can get combination by their code:

```
$product = new Product("COMB CODE");

$product->quantity = 5;  // your quantity
$product->save();
```

But PHP raises:

```
PHP Deprecated:  array_key_exists(): Using array_key_exists() on objects is deprecated. Use isset() or property_exists() instead in /home/w.sk/web/Adapter/Adapter_EntityMapper.php on line 84
PHP Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /home/w.sk/web/classes/ObjectModel.php on line 478
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Out of range value for column 'id_product' at row 1<br /><br /><pre>INSERT INTO `ps_product` (`id_shop_default`, `id_manufacturer`, `id_supplier`, `reference`, `supplier_reference`, `location`, `width`, `height`, `depth`, `weight`, `quantity_discount`, `ean13`, `upc`, `cache_is_pack`, `cache_has_attachments`, `is_virtual`, `id_category_default`, `id_tax_rules_group`, `on_sale`, `online_only`, `ecotax`, `minimal_quantity`, `price`, `wholesale_price`, `unity`, `unit_price_ratio`, `additional_shipping_cost`, `customizable`, `text_fields`, `uploadable_files`, `active`, `redirect_type`, `id_product_redirected`, `available_for_order`, `available_date`, `condition`, `show_price`, `indexed`, `visibility`, `cache_default_attribute`, `advanced_stock_management`, `date_add`, `date_upd`, `pack_stock_type`) VALUES ('1', '0', '0', '', '', '', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '', '', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '', '0', '1', '0000-00-00', 'new', '1', '0', 'both', in /home/w.sk/web/classes/db/Db.php on line 791
```

Do you know how to get existing combination and update it's quantity?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to update the combination quantity:

```
$id_product = your product id
$id_product_attribute = your combination id
$quantity = your quantity
 
StockAvailable::setQuantity($id_product,$id_product_attribute, $quantity);
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Danoosh's answer, if you have the product's ID you can do the following:

```php
$product = new Product($id_product);
$combinations = $product->getAttributeCombinations($id_lang, $groupByIdAttributeGroup); // 1, true for example

foreach ($combinations as $combination)
{
  $idAttribute = $combination['id_product_attribute']
  
  // product, id attribute (if simple product set to 0), quantity
  StockAvailable::setQuantity($product->id, $idAttribute, $quantity); // There is no need to save/update the product/combination
}
```